# How to migrate TwLauncher customization to another Launcher

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, launcher

How can I copy the home screen customization from Samsung's TwLauncher on a Galaxy S II running Android 4.0.3 to another Launcher such as Holo, Nova, GO or Apex.

I tried [Desk migrate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ma.deskmigrate) as well as the import option embedded in some of these launchers but either TwLauncher did not appear as an option to import from or it did appear but the settings were not imported.